# Extract duplicate values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to find a way of deleting duplicate shaders in Maya using Python Dictionaries.

Here is what I'm doing:

I want to put all maya shaders into a dictionary as keys and put the corresponding texture file as the value. Then I want the script to run through the dictionary and find any keys that share the same value and stuff them into an array or another dictionary.

This is basically what I have right now:

```
shaders_dict = {'a': somePath, 'b': somePath,
                'c': differentPath, 'd': differentPath}

duplicate_shaders_dict = {}`
```

how can I now run through that dictionary to compile another dictionary that looks something like this:

```
duplicate_shaders_dict = {'b':somePath, 'd':differentPath }
```

And the tricky part being since there are duplicates I want the script to `skip the original key` so it doesn't also get stuffed in to duplicate shaders dictionary.

Comment: I assume by "the original key" you mean `a` in your example. I would like to point out that dictionaries aren't ordered, and "the original key" can only mean "the first encountered".

Answer (score 4):

I would probably do something like this.  First, make the inverse dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> shaders_dict = {'a':'somePath', 'b':'somePath', 'c':'differentPath', 'd':'differentPath'}
>>> 
>>> inverse_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in shaders_dict.iteritems():
...     inverse_dict[v].append(k)
... 
>>> inverse_dict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'differentPath': ['c', 'd'], 'somePath': ['a', 'b']})
```

This basically inverts the  dictionary by looping over every key, value pair and appending the key to a list associated with the value.

Then split this:

```
>>> first_shaders_dict = {}
>>> duplicate_shaders_dict = {}
>>> for v, ks in inverse_dict.iteritems():
...     first, rest = ks[0], ks[1:]
...     first_shaders_dict[first] = v
...     for r in rest:
...         duplicate_shaders_dict[r] = v
... 
>>> first_shaders_dict
{'a': 'somePath', 'c': 'differentPath'}
>>> duplicate_shaders_dict
{'b': 'somePath', 'd': 'differentPath'}
```

Hmm.  This assumes that the texture files are hashable and so can serve as dictionary keys.  If they're not, then I'd have to work around that.  Also, since as @freespace notes there's no ordering here, if you wanted a particular order we'd have to iterate over sorted keys or the like.

--

Update: I didn't like the above much.  Shorter itertools-based version:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> shaders_dict = {'a':'somePath', 'b':'somePath', 'c':'differentPath', 'd':'differentPath'}
>>> keys = sorted(sorted(shaders_dict),key=shaders_dict.get)
>>> by_val = [(v, list(ks)) for v, ks in itertools.groupby(keys, shaders_dict.get)]
>>> first_dict = dict((ks[0],v) for v,ks in by_val)
>>> duplicate_dict = dict((k,v) for v,ks in by_val for k in ks[1:])
>>> first_dict
{'a': 'somePath', 'c': 'differentPath'}
>>> duplicate_dict
{'b': 'somePath', 'd': 'differentPath'}
```

Comment: This one did it! although it's kind of "magic" to me. I am going to study this solution.

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is to reverse the dictionary.  Given:

```
>>> d = {'a': 'somePath', 'b': 'somePath', 
... 'c': 'differentPath', 'd': 'differentPath'}
```

You can reverse it like this:

```
>>> r = dict((v,k) for k,v in d.iteritems())
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> r
{'differentPath': 'd', 'somePath': 'b'}
```

And if you reverse that, you have the original dictionary with duplicates removed:

```
>>> d = dict((v,k) for k,v in r.iteritems())
>>> d
{'b': 'somePath', 'd': 'differentPath'}
```

Comment: and where is the dict with the duplicate values?

Comment: Huh, missed that part.  This starts with the "what I have" part of the question and yields the "what I want" part, so it's probably a good place to start.

Comment: This makes sense: but I don't want to just get rid of the duplicates, I need to put them into another variable so that later on I can act on them and then delete them from the scene

Comment: Actually, I think if you don't replace the original dictionary this gets what the OP asked for.  Monkeys, let me know if you need something more.

Comment: ...we crossed lines there.  If in the last step you do something like `d1 = dict((v,k) for k,v in r.iteritems())` then you have the original dictionary in `d` and the dupes in `d1`.  Does that work?